# .NET C# unsafe/fixed CS1666 working with array of pointers to elements in another array

Tags: c#, arrays, pointers, fixed, unsafe

Warning! Sorry, I'm bad english! 
Using a fixed array in struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 12)]
public unsafe struct union_reg
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 12)]
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public fixed byte r[12]; 

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public fixed UInt16 rp[6]; 
}
```

try create and get access to elements through array of pointers:

```
union_reg reg = new union_reg();
byte*[] r = new byte*[9] { &reg.r[rB], &reg.r[rC], &reg.r[rD], &reg.r[rE], &reg.r[rH], &reg.r[rL], &rhl, &reg.r[rA], &reg.r[6] };
```

If I declarete it in function, all fine, but if I try declarete it in class, I get error CS1666. Please help solve the problem!

```
const byte rB = 1;
const byte rC = 0;
const byte rD = 3;
const byte rE = 2;
const byte rH = 5;
const byte rL = 4;
const byte rA = 7;
const byte rF = 6;`
```

Comment: Try to make fast algorythm. Emulating an old cpu.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error: how are rB, rC, rD etc defined?

Answer (score -1):

This error is clearly explained on [msdn here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/933dxtdw.aspx).

You cannot have fixed types as fields/properties inside an unfixed class.

Comment: I try it but get same error. `fixed(byte* b = &reg.r[rB]) { }`